# Wordpress Outputting Excerpt as link not working correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, slug

I need to output a custom 'read more' button for every post.

I use the following function that I've made:

```
function the_excerpt_more_link( $excerpt ){
$post = get_post();
$url = 'https:/www.vierenzestig.nl/';
$postslug = $post->post_name;
$link = $url . $postslug;
$excerpt = '<a href="'.$link.'">Lees meer!</a>';

return $link;
}
```

This is working as expected and it outputs the following :

```
https:/www.vierenzestig.nl/interior-car-wash-and-detailing-service
```

When I try to wrap the above output inside an  element. It also displays the home url from the website. Using this code (see the replacement of $link with $excerpt):

```
function the_excerpt_more_link( $excerpt ){
$post = get_post();
$url = 'https:/www.vierenzestig.nl/';
$postslug = $post->post_name;
$link = $url . $postslug;
$excerpt = '<a href="'.$link.'">Lees meer!</a>';

return $excerpt;
}
```

This outputs the following :

An link with the text: 'Lees Meer'. But the link is navigating to the following :

https://HOMEURLHERE/https:/www.vierenzestig.nl/interior-car-wash-and-detailing-service

Why is the same use of code resulting in a different output of code?